# Can I turn on a relay OUAZ-SS-105 from high on P26

Tags: microcontroller, relay

Is it possible to turn on a relay  OUAZ-SS-105D using a high on pin 26. See image

[image]

Case 1: if I replace the P26 connection with a wire to vdd the led "GOES ON". The vdd voltage is 3.3 volts.

Case 2: if I apply a high to P26 (which reads as 3.3 volts as well) the led DOES "NOT" go  on.

What is the difference of the volts from the vdd or p26?

Comment: maybe output current capability of gpio pin is lower than vdd pin ? You should specify which microcontroller you are using. Btw, if not aware, using a transistor for such circuits rather than a relay is much better. (though you won't need even a transistor for lighting an LED)

Comment: did you measure the voltage in Case 2 when the relay was connected to P26?

Comment: yes, both were 3.3 volts the output voltage of a PIN is 3.3 volts as High (a 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPIO pins of a microcontroller are weak and have no capability to drive a relay directly. In general the IO pin would drive a transistor, and the transistor would drive the relay coil. The 3.3V is also below rated operating voltage of the relay so it would not be reliable anyway to drive a 5V relay with 3.3V.

Comment: Thanks I thought so. What confused me was the GPIO put out 3.3 volts at 54ma and so did the vdd with 3.3 vols and 54 ma. Is it really the relay being a 5 volt.

Comment: @user6804473 you must be looking at the short circuit current abs max